# Determining A list of IDs filtered out of a string

Tags: php, string, parsing

So I'm working with an API that allows developers to apply filters.

Currently there's an endpoint of /users?filters=user_id:10,20,30,40 etc. but it also accepts more in line filters. For excample

/users?params=user_id:10,20,30,name:John,Date:20160601

What I'd like to know is the best way to go about determining a couple of things.

If user_id filter is set. Only get the IDs from the filter.

Comment: Is there any specific separator between each filter?

Comment: Aside from a comma, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <?php
     //Make sure the filter is set
     if(!empty($_GET['filters'])){
         $filters = $_GET['filters'];
         if(strpos($filters,'user_id') >= 0){
            preg_match('/user_id:[0-9 ,]+/',$filters,$matches);
            if(count($matches[0])){
                //Parse IDs
                $ids = substr($matches[0],(strpos($matches[0],":")+1),(strlen($matches[0])-strpos($matches[0],":")));
                $ids = explode(',',$ids);
                //In case we take in an extra comma
                if($ids[count($ids)-1] == ""){
                   unset($ids[count($ids)-1]);
                }
                //Do something with IDs here
                var_dump($ids);
             }
         }else{
            echo 'not set';
         }
     }else{
           echo 'No filters';
     }
```

Comment: That solves the first part, however now how do I only retrieve the IDS assuming there are multiple filters set?

Comment: Since you're using the same delimiter for separating both filters and filter values, you'd have to set up a parser. If you can, separate filters with a semicolon or something other than a comma.

Comment: This is handled in the code. Tested it with the data he provided.

Comment: Please see updated code that handles following commas for more filters :)

Comment: Hmmm another issue has cropped up in testing. If I have a list: user_id:1,2,3 this does not work however if I add a comma to the end, it does. It should work in both scenarios.

Comment: can you send the exact string you are using that fails? I have tried it and mine works fine in both scenarios :/

Comment: You're right! It does work. I borked it while implementing it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a combination of [isset()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [explode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)